# Is it possible to define Godot Signal in C# interface?

Tags: c#, events, delegates, godot, godot4

I have to implement damage system in my game. I have multiple classes, which may be damaged(units, planets, etc.).

Each node which may be Damaged implements IDamageable interface.
Godot signal Killed seems to be not generated and it doesn't exists.

Simplified code is here

```
public interface IDamageable
{
    [Signal]
    delegate void KilledEventHandler(Node3D target); // Will used to untarget current target of unit or remove it from UI selection info
    float HP { get;}

    bool ApplyDamage(float damage);
}

public class Unit : CharacterBody3D, IDamageable
{
    [Export]
    public float HP { get; private set; } = 10;

    public bool ApplyDamage(float damage)
    {
        HP -= damage;
        if (HP <= 0)
        {
            EmitSignal(SignalName.Killed); // SignalName.Killed doesn't exists
        }
        return HP > 0;
    }
}

public class Planet : StaticBody3D, IDamageable
{
    [Export]
    public float HP { get; private set; } = 10;

    public bool ApplyDamage(float damage)
    {
        HP -= damage;
        if (HP <= 0)
        {
            EmitSignal(SignalName.Killed); // SignalName.Killed doesn't exists
        }
        return HP > 0;
    }
}
```

Is it any possible way to define Godot Signal in C# interface?

Comment: I have no idea if this is supported. Try using the name of the signal as `String` (i.e. `"Killed"`), see https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/207026/10408

Answer (score 0):

A pull request is pending to add this functionality:
https://github.com/godotengine/godot/pull/83889
Currently unavailable.

I eventually decided to make a Damagable into a child class of (in your case) CharacterBody3D but I understand thats not the same when your planets are static.

The only workaround I can think of is handling Damagableness by components i.e. Creating a node and a Customclass extending it that handless Damage and has the signal and either not have IDamagable at all or if you think you need it you can just put Customclass as a property in it.